# What happens when you fail a hover fly check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, flight

The [fly](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/fly.html) skill is clear about when a check is needed, and you cannot perform the intended action if failing the check. Further more, it states if you fail by 5 or more, you pummel to the floor.

> **Try Again**: Varies. You can attempt a Fly check to perform the same maneuver on subsequent rounds. **If you are using wings and you fail a Fly check by 5 or more, you plummet to the ground**, taking the appropriate falling damage (see Environment).

Now, in the case of the *hover* maneuver, not being able to perform the check, but failing by less than 5, what are their consequences?

Do you lose height? What amount?

Are you forced to move more than half your speed? What if you cannot?

Comment: For those that don't want to suffer the consequences of a failing by 5 or more, remember to never attempt a maneuver you can't complete by "taking 5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no specific written penalties for failing to Hover, but it implied that there are penalties of some sort.

The implied RAW is that if you fail the Hover check, you would then be required to make a valid flight movement:

> Without making a check, a flying creature can remain flying at the end of its turn so long as it moves a distance greater than half its speed. It can also turn up to 45 degrees by sacrificing 5 feet of movement, can rise at half speed at an angle of 45 degrees.

Also possible, a GM could rule that you fall 10-20 feet or cannot take another action that turn as you are not stable trying to stay in your current location. Alternately, they could require you to *use* your Standard action as a Move action and attempt another Fly check.

Answer (score 2):

### You simply fail the maneuver, and possibly fall and take damage.

The [Fly](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/fly.html) skill rules makes no exception to what use of the skill you are doing, as such, the consequences for *any* failure are the same:

> If you are using wings and you fail a Fly check by 5 or more, you plummet to the ground, taking the appropriate falling damage (see Environment).

Not only that but if you fail a check you cannot attempt to avoid the damage from the fall:

> Avoid Falling Damage: If you are falling and have the ability to fly, you can make a DC 10 Fly check to negate the damage. **You cannot make this check if you are falling due to a failed Fly check** or a collision.

In other words, you will have to move at least *half your movement*, being forced to spend a *Move Action* to remain flying, or fall and take falling damage:

> Without making a check, a flying creature can remain flying at the end of its turn so long as it moves a distance greater than half its speed.

Comment: But what happens if something prevents to make that move? For example, you are surrounded by enemies or obstacles?

Comment: How would that prevent your fall? If the ground is 5 feet away, you won't take falling damage, but it didn't stop you from falling.